# Can't connect to Mosquitto through websockets

Tags: linux, node.js, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I installed the latest Mosquitto MQTT broker on Linux with websokets support, and I edit the config file to add a listener for websockets.

I add these line to the config file:

```
listener 1883
protocol mqtt
listener 1884
protocol websockets
```

when I run

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

the broker starts up and one of the lines in the console shows

```
Opening websockets listen socket on port 1884.
```

and no further error. I think the websocket listener should be up and running. When I test the broker with mqtt.js in Node.js, mqtt works well, but I can't connect to the broker through websockets.

The JS code:

```
var wsClient = mqtt.connect('ws://my.server.address:1884')

wsClient.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('ws connected')
})

wsClient.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err)
})
```

After running the JS code, I see no error or connected message. The broker didn't show any message about the ws connection either.

The strange thing is, I get this whole thing working on another Ubuntu system, but on this one, a Red Hat system, only the mqtt connection is working, ws doesn't seem to work, but shows no error on either side.

What could be causing the problem?

THX.

**UPDATE**

I tried to run the program on the server where the broker is, using `ws://127.0.0.1:1884` as target, and it gets connected. But from a remote machine, say my laptop or other server, websokcets still don't work.

Comment: How long have you left it trying to connect? Do you get a timeout message if you leave it longer?

Comment: @Leon, yes, I ran `sudo netstat -lnp| grep 1884` and it showed that mosquitto is listening on that port.

Comment: @hardillb, I left it trying to connect about 5 or 6 minutes, no timeout error. I tried to listen to `close` and `offline` event, found that it gets disconnected occasionally, and immediately tried to reconnect. However, the error event is never triggered.

Comment: Firewall rules on the server?

Answer (score 1):

After consulting the service provider of the VPS, I'm sure that there is nothing wrong with my code or the broker. Like @hardillb said, this is a firewall issue on the server. The service provider blocked all HTTP transmission， so the client can't establish a websocket connection with the server.